# Show that n is a perfect square if and only if $k_i$ is even for $ 1 \leq i \leq m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that $n = p_{1}^{k_1} p_{2}^{k_2} ... p_{m}^{k_m}$, where $p_1<p_2<...<p_m$ are all prime. Show that n is a perfect square if and only if $k_i$ is even for  $1 \leq i \leq m$

I'm not sure where to start. Maybe by contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Suppose all the exponents are even.  Find an integer $m$ such that $n=m^2$.

Step 2.  Suppose $n$ is a perfect square.  Then there is some integer $m$ such that $n=m^2$.  Use unique factorization of $m$ into primes to deduce that all the exponents of $n$ must be even.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help.